# Is Ansible Vault FIPS 140-2 certified?

Tags: encryption

What security level of FIPS 140-2 compliance standard would Ansible Vault fall under? Is there a guide or playbook that someone can share? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what Security Level you're referring to.  Ansible Vault does use the correct ciphers to be FIPS compliant but the encryption modules implementing those ciphers don't appear to be FIPS certified.  It doesn't appear that Ansible Vault is FIPS 140-2 (FIPS) compliant from that stand point.  You may have to reach out to Red Hat for a definitive answer.

That being said, I can find no evidence that any `python` modules are FIPS 140-2 certified.  The only Red Hat modules that are certified appear to only be tested for the Linux kernel.

The Veterans Administration link below specifically calls out ansible-vault in the footnotes as not being usable because it's not FIPS compliant.

**References**
[Veterans Administration Tool Page](https://www.oit.va.gov/Services/TRM/ToolPage.aspx?tid=8196&tab=2&minYear=2018) 
[Red Hat Fips Certifications](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search?SearchMode=Basic&Vendor=Red%20Hat&CertificateStatus=Active&ValidationYear=0)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.oit.va.gov/Services/TRM/ToolPage.aspx?tid=8196&tab=2&minYear=2022

2.13 is allowed per the above [www.oit.va.gov](http://www.oit.va.gov) site.  approved version will change as SSL 3.0 comes online.

Comment: "SSL"? Do you mean the next major version number of Ansible Vault?

Comment: SSL 3.0 is deprecated and not to be used...